# Acompanhar progresso de envio usando base64

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código

```js
function readFile() {
  
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    
    var FR= new FileReader();
    
    FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      document.getElementById("img").src       = e.target.result;
      document.getElementById("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
      console.log(e.target.result) 
      
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://postman-echo.com/post",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
            imageBase64:e.target.result
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.status == 404) {
                console.log("error")
            } 
        }
    });
      
      
      
    }); 
    
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
  
}

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" type='file'>
<p id="b64"></p>
<img id="img" height="150">
```

Gostaria de acompanhar o progresso de envio da imagem, usando base64, com javascript puro ou jquery.

É possível ?

Comment: Vc quer fazer a "Load Bar" com Base64? Não seria melhor com CSS?

Comment: Quero acompanhar o progresso de envio do base64 para o meu servidor.